# I can't subclass MS Access form if the window of IDE has been opened

Tags: windows, ms-access, winapi, ide, subclass

What I am doing is by using SetWindowLong I change an address of an original window procedure of a window(a form in my case) to an address of my own WindowProc, then I process one of system messages and finally I pass the intercepted message to the original window procedure.

I tested intercepting messages subclassing:

- A window of MS Access instance
- A window of a form in an overlapping interface

Both of the tests go well only if I run the main Access window without opening an IDE window before or during the test. The trouble happens if at the time of testing not only MS Access main window is open but a window of IDE too.

The problem doesn’t arise in a first case (intercepting messages of MS Access window). While as the second case is a pain in the neck indeed (intercepting messages of a form in an overlapping interface). What happens is MS Access stops responding to user’s input. It looks like it gets looping and looping endlessly. I’d like to stress once more that such behavior takes place only when MS Access window and window of IDE are open at the same time.

I made a test file so that you can see it for yourself. I uploaded it here:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/8lnqfgb1hn3zqy8/SetWindowLong.accdb?dl=0

So, the first case(when there is no problem):

- Open the file (**DO NOT open IDE window till the end of the test**)
- Open Form1(on opening the system messages to MS Access window will start being intercepted)
- Close Form1(on closing intercepting will be stopped)
- Open Form 2(on opening the system messages to Form2 window will get being intercepted)
- Close Form2(on closing intercepting will be stopped)

So far so good.

Now the second case (the pain in the neck):

- Open the file
- Open IDE window (ALT+F11)
- Open Form1(on opening the system messages to MS Access window will get being intercepted)
- Close Form1(on closing intercepting will be stopped)
- Open Form 2(on opening the system messages to Form2 window are intended to get being intercepted, but **you will witness an endless looping and no response from Access**)

And now are my questions:

- How come an open window of IDE can interfere in my subclassing of Form2 and does not affect the subclassing of MS Access window.
- What can be done so that I was able to subclass Form2 while the window of IDE stayed open

I will be very grateful for your advice.

Edited on 2017/08/25:
Sorry for not providing my code at the beginning.

In a standard module of MS Access:

```vb
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Private Declare Function CallWindowProc Lib "user32" Alias "CallWindowProcA" (ByVal lpPrevWndFunc As Long, ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal Msg As Long, ByVal wParam As Long, ByVal lParam As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function SetWindowLong Lib "user32" Alias "SetWindowLongA" (ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal nIndex As Long, ByVal dwNewLong As Long) As Long
Public lngPrevWndProc As Long

Public Function WndProc(ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal uMsg As Long, ByVal wParam As Long, ByVal lParam As Long) As Long
    WndProc = CallWindowProc(lngPrevWndProc, hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam)
End Function
```

In a code module of Form2:

```vb
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Private Declare Function SetWindowLong Lib "user32" Alias "SetWindowLongA" (ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal nIndex As Long, ByVal dwNewLong As Long) As Long
Private Const GWL_WNDPROC = -4

Private Sub Form_Open(Cancel As Integer)
    lngPrevWndProc = SetWindowLong(Me.hWnd, GWL_WNDPROC, AddressOf WndProc)
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Unload(Cancel As Integer)
    SetWindowLong Me.hWnd, GWL_WNDPROC, lngPrevWndProc
End Sub
```

This sample intended to work on a 32bit Windows and in 32bit MS Access. I tested it on:
Windows XP Pro + MS Access 2000 (the file was converted to mdb); Windows 7 32bit + MS Access 2010 32bit (accdb); indows 10 32bit + MS Access 2016 32bit (accdb)

The result was the same as I described before.

Sergiy Vakshul

Comment: Check the owner/parent windows and classes and find a rule what windows you want to subclass and what windows you don't want...

Comment: @xMRi, thanks for your response. I am afraid I didn’t grasp the idea. You say “find a rule what windows you want to subclass and what windows you don't want”. I want to subclass the Form2 window. And I do so by specifying the handle of my aim(Form2) by this line SetWindowLong(Me.hWnd, GWL_WNDPROC, AddressOf WndProc).

Comment: @xMRi, You also say “Check the owner/parent windows and classes”. Do you mean the owner/parent for my Form2? GetAncestor(hWndForm2, GA_ROOT) = GetAncestor(hWndForm2, GA_ROOTOWNER) = Application.hWndAccessApp. I mean that the owner/parent for my Form2 is MS Access main window. Please, can you add a bit more to your post to help me grasp what you mean.

Comment: Subclassing controls using `SetWindowLong` has been wrong since the first 64-bit Windows OS (Windows XP 64-Bit Edition, released in 2001). Likewise, subclassing controls using `SetWindowLongPtr` has been wrong for more than a decade and a half (see [Subclassing Controls](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773183.aspx) for the safe and sane alternative).

Comment: @IInspectable, thank you very much for the attention you payed to my question. Indeed, I knew nothing of SetWindowSubclass. I’ll definitely experiment with it. As for SetWindowLong I have to admit all the examples I’ve looked through don’t use ComCtl32.dll but a user32.dll and the sample I uploaded as well. More than that, in spite of me uploading accdb file I also tested mdb file in Assess 2000 on Windows XP Pro and the result was exactly the same as I described in the post. What do you think of it?

Comment: @SergiyVakshul: Make sure you are trying to subclass the correct window in the first place, and that you are not trying to subclass a window that belongs to another thread/process.  You can't subclass windows over thread/process boundaries.  If you need to do that, you have to use a message hook via `SetWindowsHookEx()` instead. How are you determining which window to subclass? **You didn't show any code!**  Please provide a [mcve], or your question is likely to be closed as off-topic.

Comment: @ Remy Lebeau, thank you for answering. I added the code as you advised.

Comment: @IInspectable, thanks for drawing my attention to SetWindowSubclass. I rewrote the code using the approach laid down here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1120337/4810876 Unfortunately, the result is almost the same: if IDE hasn’t been open then the code runs smoothly, but once IDE gets open something gets broken and Access stops responding. I could show the new code adding it to my post if you’ll get interested.